# CRUD de datos con bootstrap y PHP

Tags: php, html, crud

Tengo un problema con algunas sentencias que estoy usando para un CRUD de datos con bootstrap, php y html.

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual realizo la conexión a la BD sin incluir una librería externa.

```
<?php
            function conectar_bd($query)
    {
      $DB_SERVER = "localhost";
        $DB_USER = "root";
        $DB_DATABASE = "dbAdmin";
        $DB_PWD = "12345";

      $conn=mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_DATABASE);
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
           echo mysqli_connect_error();
        return $result;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores ORDER BY Nombre ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);   ##LINEA DE ERROR
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){ ##LINEA DE ERROR 
                echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No hay datos.</td></tr>';
            }else{
                $no = 1;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row['idAdmin'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Nombre'].'</td>
          <td>'.$row['Usuario'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['RPE'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['admin_desde'].'</td>
                        <td>

                            <a href="edit.php?nik='.$row['idAdmin'].'" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

                            <a href="consultaadmin.php?aksi=delete&nik='.$row['idAdmin'].'" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm(\'Esta seguro de borrar los datos '.$row['idAdmin'].'?\')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                    $no++;
                }
            }
            ?>
```

El caso es el que me tira estos dos errores al ejecutar en el navegador y no me muestra la consuta.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema.tics\consultaadmin.php on line 73
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema.tics\consultaadmin.php on line
>   74

Mi tabla existe y ya verifique que todos los nombres tanto de tabla y rows esten bien.

Comment: te actuialicé mi respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, ya me ha funcionado, muchas gracias una vez mas por la ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

Te comento que dentro de mysqli, la configuración debe ser del modo siguiente

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

> Es decir primero va la variable que conlleva por dentro la conexión y
>   luego la variable que esta guardando la query

---

> Con respecto al error que te menciona que `num_rows()` recibió un
>   valor nulo, es por que esa tratando de usar la variable `$result`,
>   pero la misma llega de `mysqli_query()` que le falta la variable
>   `$conn` por tanto no se procesa exitosamente la consulta y llega con
>   un valor `NUll`

Deacuerdo a la propia documentación de PHP y cito:

***Valores devueltos  Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del
tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query()
retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de
mysqli_query() retornará TRUE.***

Fuente: 
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Te propongo dejes tu código de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

      $DB_SERVER = "localhost";
        $DB_USER = "root";
        $DB_DATABASE = "dbAdmin";
        $DB_PWD = "12345";

      $conn=mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_DATABASE);
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);   ##LINEA DE ERROR
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){ ##LINEA DE ERROR 
                echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No hay datos.</td></tr>';
            }else{
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row['idAdmin'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Nombre'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Usuario'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['RPE'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['admin_desde'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

> Quité la función de conectar y solo invoco a dicha variable de manera
>   directa donde es requerida, hice un ejemplo en local y es funcional

Comment: Ahora se añade un error más Undefined variable: conn, estando ya declarado en la parte inicial.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que especificar a que conexion vas a realizar el query asi:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Ahora al ponerlo así me arroja los mismo errores y además Undefined variable: conn, estando ya declarado en la parte inicial

Comment: @JairMejíaLópez no te va reconocer la conexion dado que la estas usando en la funcion conectar_bd..una vez ejecutas la consulta o query de dicha funcion (conectar_bd) la conexion se cierra , por lo tanto en las siguientes lineas no te reconoce y te sale undefined.. debes crear una funcion solo para conexion y mandar a llamar dicha conexion cuando desees ejecutar un query

Comment: Al parecer fue cuestión de no cerrar bien la llave de la ejecución de la función conectar_bd. Ahora ya no me tira ningún error pero en la tabla no se visualiza ningún registro.